# javascript - Bootstrap modal dialog with yes/no not working with imagebutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use ImageButton to fire Bootstrap modal popup but it is not firing for some reason. Please help. Here is my code

```
      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/img/Delete.png" CausesValidation="false"  ToolTip="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

here is my modal popup code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">s                               

                               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" CausesValidation="false" > 
                                                                <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>No
                                </asp:LinkButton>

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" > 
                                                                <i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Yes
                                </asp:LinkButton>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div>
```

here is JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          function ShowPopup2() {
            $("#btnShowPopup2").click();
          }
        </script>
```

Comment: No element has the id `btnShowPopup2` so triggering a click event won't do anything.

Comment: i thought by adding this in the imagebutton will trigger the modal: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"